# JavaFX, container that can switch between two panes with transition effect

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am looking for a container in JavaFX for my Desktop Application that initially holds a listview with its width = parent's width and height as per the number of rows. Upon clicking, any of the rows (if any), the list shall hide itself with a transition effect and the container should show now a gridpane that now lists the detail of the row that was selected. If i go back(back button in gridpane), the previous listview shall become visible with a transition effect and the gridpane shall be hidden. I tried borderpane to hold both panes in its center and right but that did not go as planned. Please guide if there are any existing containers that JavaFx provides or any custom that are present on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

a code example of the gridpane might be very helpfull to help you.

Did you set the pane's percentages and widths? And did you use a cardlayout to switch between the listview and the selected item detail panel? The trouble is may be determing the listview width itself because the width of the listview depends on the items used inside the (scrollist) listView items

Comment: Hi, at the end i had to resort to javafx Tabpane, hid the tab buttons, now everything works as expected. Thanks for your help.